# Wordpress Multisite with localhost and 8090 port

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mamp, multisite

**Problem**

Im trying to setup a local working sub domain `Wordpress` multisite on the port `8090`.

**Setup**

- MAMP Stack with SQL on port 3306, Apache on 8080.
- Wordpress 4.4 installed on path: /Users/x/y/website/www/wordpress
- Running PHP Webserver in IntelliJ on port 8090.

**Error** (when trying to install multisite network in the admin wordpress section)

> Error: You cannot install a network of sites with your server address
>
> You cannot use port numbers such as :8090.

Therefore I changed my apache2 httpd.config file.

**httpd.config**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and added virtual hosts

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/x/Environment/mampstack-5.4.32-0/
apache2/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/x/y/website/www"
ServerName testproject.dev
<Directory "/Users/x/y/website/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I changed the /etc/host.

**/etc/host**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost testproject.dev

# later on for mulisite sub domains
127.0.0.1 localhost.com
127.0.0.1 subdomain.localhost.com
```

I restarted the whole MAMP setup, flushed the cache for the htaccess file and restarted my php server. But I still got the same error and cant setup my multisite in Wordpress.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a network in the following cases:

- "WordPress address (URL)" is different from "Site address (URL)".
- "WordPress address (URL)" uses a port number other than ':80', ':443'.

Change your port to 80 for wordpress multisites is a simple solution.

Comment: What if I need 80 for production and I want to prototype my network on other ports?